# Difference between "(NSSet *)touches" and "event.allTouches" in "touchesBegan:withEvent:"

Tags: ios, uiimageview, multi-touch

I need to move, rotate and zoom an UIImageView object. In the method...

```
touchesBegan(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

which touches do I have to use?

```
(NSSet *)touches
```

or

```
event.allTouches
```

In other words, where are my touches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`touches` passed as the parameter are the touches in your view.

`event.allTouches` contains all the touches of the event, even the one that didn't start in your view.

Don't hesitate to [read the Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) in Apple's doc, it is explained with some pictures it will probably help you understand better.

Especially [the difference between the `touches` in the parameters and `event.allTouches` is described here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW18) ;)

Comment: Ok. So, if I want only touches on the imageView I have to move/rotate/zoom, I have to consider the "touches" parameter. The same thing in touchesMoved.

Comment: Yep, exactly :) Actually you quite never have to use `event.allTouches` (I never had to use it myself ever) but always use the `touches` parameter. Anyway: (1) IIRC there is already sample code in Apple's doc for implementing drag&drop&rotate&zoom if you are interested, and (2) **you should use UIGestureRecognizers** instead of managing touches yourself **if you are simply implementing standard gestures like move/zoom/rotate**: it would be really easier to code. There is a type of UIGestureRecognizer for there 3 actions, see in the same documentation for explanations and samples.